# How do I make the output in this hangman game keep its previouse outputs?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a hangman game in python, it works but I want to make the UserGuesses list remember all inputs.

```
import random

HangmanWords = random.choice(open('words.txt').readlines())
word = str(HangmanWords)
w = word.strip()
#Tries = number letters
NumOfTries = len(w)

score = []
def turns(NumOfTries,w,score):
  UserGuesses = []
  UI = str(raw_input('Guess a letter (caps only): '))

  for i in w:
    if UI == i:
      score.append('Yes')
      UserGuesses.append(UI)
    else:
      UserGuesses.append('_')

  print UserGuesses

  while NumOfTries > 0:
    turns(NumOfTries - 1,w,score)
    break

turns(NumOfTries,w,score)

S = len(score)
print 'Score:',S,'/',NumOfTries
print 'The word was:', word
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\owner\Desktop\P\HangmanPython>python hangman.py
Guess a letter (caps only): A
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): S
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'S', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): W
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): R
['R', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): G
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): Y
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): H
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): O
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter (caps only): P
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Score: 2 / 8
The word was: RUMMIEST
```

I would like for each list to keep the previous output, for the third list and all the ones after that, to keep the 'S'.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in each recursion of the `turns` function , you are re-initializing the UserGuesses variable, instead you can try defining it outside the function and use it inside, I believe that is possible in python, but then you will also need to keep track of the index of letters in the word, and instead of doing `UserGuesses.append` , you will need to change the index value, something like -

```
import random

HangmanWords = random.choice(open('words.txt').readlines())
word = str(HangmanWords)
w = word.strip()
#Tries = number letters
NumOfTries = len(w)

score = []
def turns(NumOfTries,w,score):
  UI = str(raw_input('Guess a letter (caps only): '))

  j = 0
  for i in w:
    if UI == i:
      score.append('Yes')
      UserGuesses[j] = UI
    j = j + 1

  print UserGuesses

  while NumOfTries > 0:
    turns(NumOfTries - 1,w,score)
    break


UserGuesses = ['_' for i in w]
turns(NumOfTries,w,score)

S = len(score)
print 'Score:',S,'/',NumOfTries
print 'The word was:', word
```

Answer (score 1):

And without recursion:

```
import random

HangmanWords = random.choice(open('words.txt').readlines())
word = str(HangmanWords)
w = word.strip()
NumOfTries = len(w)

def turns(NumOfTries, word):
  score = 0
  guesses = set()
  for i in range(len(w)):
    guess = str(raw_input('Guess a letter (caps only): '))
    guesses.add(guess)
    if guess in word:
      score += 1
    print [c if c in guesses else "_" for c in w]
  return score

score = turns(NumOfTries, w)

print 'Score:', score, '/', NumOfTries
print 'The word was:', word
```

We don't need a list for the score.